# Laravel Eloquent in jQuery Script

Tags: php, jquery, laravel

**EDIT**
I just realized I didn't post the entire code.

I am using an Ajax live search to retrieves cards when a user types in a part of their last name. When the results appear, a user will click on the row and it will retrieve that cards information.

From there, I want to use the card information to generate additional html.

```
        $.ajax({
               type: "get",
               url : '{{ route('compare.search') }}',
               data: {'search':$(this).val()},
               success: function(data) {
                   $("#suggestion-box-1").slideDown();
                   $("#suggestion-box-1 tbody").html(data);

                   $(data).each(function(index){
                     $("#suggestion-box-1 tbody").append('<tr><td><a href="#" class="player-name" data-card=' + data[index].id + '>' + data[index].first + ' ' + data[index].last + '</a></td><td><span class="card-type"></span>' + data[index].card_type.replace('-', ' ') + '</td><td align="center"><span class="card-overall">' + data[index].overall + '</span></td></tr>');

                   });

                   // This is the part that I can't figure out
                   $('#suggestion-box-1 .player-name').click(function() {
                     var cid = $(this).data('card');
                     var card = {!! App\Card::where("id", $cid)->get() !!};
                     console.log(card);

                   });

               }
           });
      } else if (len == 0) $('#suggestion-box-1').slideUp();
    });
```

Any sort of help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: You can't mix javascript and php like this. PHP is executed on the server (before anything is sent to the browser) and javascript is executed in the browser. This means that the query will have already run before javascript can do anything. Look at using ajax.

Comment: @Rwd I am using Ajax. I updated my original post with the full code. It is a live search using Ajax, and when a user clicks on a specific result it will retrieve the card data.

Comment: Are you opposed to using [Vue.js](https://vuejs.org/) ? I think you might find it helpful for this, so you're not mixing in the `<html>` there. ( bonus: reusable components! ).

Comment: Making use of [scoped slots](https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-slots.html#Scoped-Slots) could make this a breeze

Answer (score 2):

That's gonna be impossible without an API since blade won't talk back to the server for that function.

You'll need to create an API endpoint that takes that javascript `cid` variable and responds with the card information you need.

The flow is blade generates the page THEN the cid variable gets populated in the frontend so `cid` doesn't exist at the moment the `::where` function is called.

Comment: I have updated my original post because it did not contain the entire code as I previously thought.